# MySQL date result split by date

Tags: mysql, sorting, date, split

I have a query that show results of projects being worked between 2 dates. I would like the results to show me something like this

For: 2011-07-11

- Result 1
- Result 2
- Result 3

For: 2011-07-12

- Result 4
- Result 5
  etc...

So it's showing me the results split by date. Is that possible with a MySQL query ? Or I will need to make a query for each date ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want separate queries for the two dates or just the results to be grouped by the two dates in the same query?

Comment: Well it's between 2 dates so the range could be 1 week or a months of results. So if it could be in the same query that could gimme the results for each date between them and group them in a classy way so I can see the result for each date, it could be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there really isn't a way to make this sort of query 'classy' if you're going to be pulling all of the information from a single query. You can't make anything other than a rectangular table and therefore can't represent many-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many relationships in a classier way. If you want to do something like this I would recommend using a server-side scripting language to take care of it for you and display it however you want (that is unless this isn't a web-based application, then just use a non-web language).

In order to pull all the data and group/sort by the date, you would do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM myDB.myTable
GROUP BY theDateValue
ORDER BY theDateValue ASC;
```

This will pull all records from the table, group them by their relevant dates, and then sort them in ascending order by the date value(s).

Comment: That helped to get me in the right way. But this was the best anwser for me http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/php-34/display-mysql-results-sorted-dates-headers-132525.html

Comment: Yep. Like I said if you want something like that you'll have to use a server-side scripting language, which is what the link you've supplied is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what your asking can be done in the presentation layer of your application. You could use a tree control, or a grid/table with grouping etc to present the data as a Heading-Sub Heading or Master-Detail layout. You would need to iterate over the records returned and then group them in the desired manner.